# Cross (also called in-line or sub) brake levers compatible with SRAM Apex

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, cyclocross, brake-levers

Does somebody know of cross/in-line/sub brake levers compatible with SRAM Apex? Could the Shimano GRX sub brake levers perhaps work?

See https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/BL-RX812-L.html

Thank you!

Comment: Shimano uses mineral oil in their brakes. SRAM uses DOT fluid. The fluids and components from the systems can't mix due to seal <-> fluid incompatibility. More importantly, why do you feel you need/want sub-levers?

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks a lot for the reply. The fluid incompatibility is a pity, indeed. I had read about it but was not sure if the incompatibility was both ways. 

I want sub-levers simply for safety (and confort) reasons. When having the hands on the horizontal bar, it takes half a second to switch position and be able to pull the brakes. Half a second is a lot when it comes to avoiding a sudden danger, hence my interest in sub-levers.

Comment: My point is that sub levers aren't a good way to stop in an emergency. It's just a bad/unstable position for your body to brace itself for an emergency deceleration. I think your money would be better spent paying for a professional bike fit such that the hoods of your existing drop bar levels are a comfortable enough to be your default position on the bike

Comment: I get your point, although I must say that, for having had a cyclocross bike with sub levers 25 years ago, I found it pretty decent at braking back then. Of course, if I had to choose where to brake from, I would go for the hooks, obviously ;-) But when an upright position is useful (i.e. resting, or cycling over rough terrain), I think gripping the bars is a reflex, is it not? But I take good note of your suggestion. You are right, I could perhaps simply switch my stem to bring the handle closer/higher and allow for a more upright riding position from the hoods.

Comment: Found this, but Hope just told me that they will never mass-produce this prototype: https://road.cc/content/tech-news/206054-hope-unveils-new-inline-hydraulic-crosstop-brake-levers-paul-oldham-winning